# Brainf**k interpreter in Ruby

Tags: programming-challenge, ruby, interpreter, brainfuck

I wrote this interpreter for a code challenge. Can this be written any cleaner/smaller? Could I reduce the amount of nested conditional/loops?

```
def brain_luck(code, input)
  output = ''
  cp = 0 # code pointer
  dp = 0 # data pointer
  ip = 0 # input pointer
  data = Array.new(10, 0)
  while cp < code.length
    case code[cp]
    when '>'
      dp += 1
      if dp == data.length
        data.push(0)
      end
    when '<'
      dp -= 1
      if dp == -1
        dp = 0
        data.unshift(0)
      end
    when '+'
      data[dp] = (data[dp].ord+1)%256
    when '-'
      data[dp] = (data[dp].ord-1)%256
    when '.'
      output += data[dp].chr
    when ','
      data[dp] = input[ip].ord
      ip += 1
    when '['
      if data[dp] == 0
        nest_count = 1
        while nest_count > 0
          case code[cp += 1]
          when '[' then nest_count += 1
          when ']' then nest_count -= 1
          end
        end
      end
    when ']' 
      if data[dp] != 0
        nest_count = 1
        while nest_count > 0
          case code[cp -= 1]
          when ']' then nest_count += 1
          when '[' then nest_count -= 1
          end
        end
      end
    end
    cp += 1
  end
  output
end
```

Comment: I know you don't want to swear, but `brain_luck` is not the way to go. It's confusing since it doesn't make sense why there is a function like that. You could just do something like `eval_program`.

Comment: `brain_luck` was how the code challenge presented it (same with the double `*` in `brainf**k`)

Comment: Ok, if you need to submit it that way for the challenge, but outside of the challenge, I would highly recommend changing it. :)

Comment: Does it work for this BF-program now? `,>+>>>>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<<<<<<[>[>>>>>>+>+<<<<<<<-]>>>>>>>[<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>-]<[>++++++++++[-<-[>>+>+<<<-]>>>[<<<+>>>-]+<[>[-]<[-]]>[<<[>>>+<<<-]>>[-]]<<]>>>[>>+>+<<<-]>>>[<<<+>>>-]+<[>[-]<[-]]>[<<+>>[-]]<<<<<<<]>>>>>[++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.[-]]++++++++++<[->-<]>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.[-]<<<<<<<<<<<<[>>>+>+<<<<-]>>>>[<<<<+>>>>-]<-[>>.>.<<<[-]]<<[>>+>+<<<-]>>>[<<<+>>>-]<<[<+>-]>[<+>-]<<<-]`

Comment: @SimonForsberg sure does ;)

Answer (score 1):

Sure it can!

Steps I see to make it clean:

1. Create a class, define state attrs:

   ```
   private

   attr_reader :output, :code_pointer, :data_pointer, :input_pointer
   ```
2. define initialize method

   ```
   def initialize(args = {})
     @code = args[:code]
     @input = args[:input]
     @output = ''
     @code_pointer, @data_pointer, @input_pointer = 0, 0, 0
   end
   ```
3. define `whens` as a methods and give it right names: `next_cell`, `prev_cell`, `increment`, `decrement`, `write_byte`, `read_byte` and so on
4. define constant for configuration:

   ```
   OPERATORS = {
     '>' => :next_cell,
     '<' => :prev_cell,
     '+' => :increment,
     ...
   }
   ```
5. define method to evaluate code:

   ```
   def evaluate_code
     code.each { |operator| public_send OPERATORS[operator] }
   end
   ```
6. Finally instantiate object of your class and call evaluate_code

   ```
   BrainLuck.new(code: code, input: input).evaluate_code
   ```

I think you'll love your object oriented result.